# How can I get GMail to sort starred threads by most recent reply instead of most recent star?

Tags: gmail

This changed 6-12 months ago. At some point, GMail's "Starred First" and "Starred" mail views started sorting conversations by the most recently starred email. This means that new replies to old starred conversations can entirely miss my attention, because they show up on page two (or further back). How can I avoid/fix this?

EDIT: This has gotten worse since the mobile app has lost the ability to star specific emails in a thread.

Comment: This is still a problem, right?

Comment: @Michaël yep. long since determined it's never going to get fixed.

Comment: Anybody?.......

Answer (score 2):

If you hover over the Inbox button in gmail, it will give you a drop down arrow. You need to change this from "Stared First" to "Unread First". This will still reserve your conversations, and they will just pop to the top of the list when someone replies. Just look for the stars to see the important one, or add flags to add more organization to different types of contacts.

All of the read conversations will be in a separate section called "Everything Else"

Good Luck!

Comment: This puts unread conversations at the top, and lets read starred conversations scroll off the bottom. I want starred at the top.

Comment: If you are getting new emails replies in stared conversations they will show up with all your other unread emails in this section, you will have to look to the left to see the stars pop up. The only reason I could see them scrolling off the bottom is if you are getting more then 25-50 emails a day or don't check your email daily. I use this method at work, and it's really easy to spot the stars with the non stars in the unread section. Hope this helps.

Comment: I definitely get more than 25 emails in a day. And some of my starred emails are a week old.